# Difference between $('body,html').scrollTop(); and $(window).scrollTop();

Tags: jquery, wordpress, window, scrolltop

I don't really understand this because sometimes body,html works and sometimes window. I've already done 2 web pages (local) with jQuery; in the first one body,html works and in the other one it doesn't, so I write window and work it, the first web page is just an html document with some css and the script for jQuery, the other one is a web page based in WordPress.org theme (my own theme).

Comment: Are you using `overflow:hidden` for any of those sites in the `body` or `html` tags styles?

Comment: Show. Relevant. Code. Also, what does it mean "doesn't work"? Error message? Browser crashes?

Comment: well yes and no, i don't get any error message just appears always 0 the value given for .scrollTop();

Comment: #main_menu {
    z-index: 9998; /*Put the menu over everything in the lvl 9998*/
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    background:#C52F30;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed; /*menu is always in the screen!!!*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: well that's not exactly the style of the body or html just modify one of mi 'div' called main_menu but it's the only overflow:hidden; in my code and as you can see i'm a little noob over here. :P sorry

Answer (score 0):

Body and Html are DOM objects therefore styling can be applied to them, In this case

```
height:100%
```

or

```
position:fixed;
```

As a result the html and body tags don't move. make the scrolltop constantly 0